# Removing unwanted characters from a string

Tags: c#, rss

I have a program where I take a date from an RSS file and attempt to convert it into a `DateTime`. Unfortunately, the RSS file that I have to use has a lot of spacing issues. When I parse the string I get this:

```
"\t\t\n\t\t4/13/2011\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t"
```

I want to remove all of the `\t`'s and`\n`'s. So far these have all failed:

```
finalDateString.Trim('\t');
finalDateString.Trim('\n');
finalDateString.Trim();
finalDateString.Replace("\t", "");
finalDateString.Replace("\n", "");
finalDateString.Replace(" ", "");
```

Every one of the commands will return the same string. Any suggestions?

(I tagged RSS in the case that there is an RSS reason for this)

Comment: Regex.Split(input, @"\D+"); will give u the numbers

Comment: What does the string look like in your quick watch? Perhaps the literal string of `@"\t"` is coming accross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can remove all the whitespace from your string by using a 1-character regular expression:

```
    String finalDateTimeString = "\t\t\n\t\t4/13/2011\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t";
    Regex whitespaceRegex = new Regex("\\s");
    finalDateTimeString = whitespaceRegex.Replace(finalDateTimeString, "");
```

I just tested this, and it worked.

Second, I just tested calling `DateTime.Parse()` on your string, and it worked without even removing the whitespace. So maybe you don't even have to do that.

```
    String finalDateTimeString = "\t\t\n\t\t4/13/2011\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t";
    DateTime finalDateTime = DateTime.Parse(finalDateTimeString);
    // finalDateTime.toString() == "4/13/2011 12:00:00 AM"
```

Comment: +1 for `DateTime.Parse` (and, by extension, `DateTime.TryParse`).

Answer (score 6):

You need to assign the original value the `Replace` output. You do not need to do the trim either as the replace will get rid of all of them.

```
finalDateString = finalDateString.Replace("\t", "");
finalDateString = finalDateString.Replace("\n", "");
```

Comment: Kudos for pointing out why it wasn't working. For that matter, the asker could probably just use `finalDateString = finalDateString.trim();`

Comment: True, I would go with the RegEx myself.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Regular expressions

```
string strRegex = @"([\s])";    
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
string strTargetString = @"  4/13/2011    ";
string strReplace = "";

string result = myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Answer (score 0):

using [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(data,"[\\t,\\n]",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

All the previously posted answers remove all whitespace from the string, but it would be more robust to only remove leading and trailing whitespace.

```
finalDateTimeString = Regex.Replace(finalDateTimeString, @"^\s+", "");
finalDateTimeString = Regex.Replace(finalDateTimeString, @"\s+$", "");
```

[ I don't know C#, so I'm guessing at the syntax from the other posts. Corrections welcome. ]

Comment: The `string.Replace` method doesn't accept regular expressions.

Comment: Sure, but then that's what `string.Trim()` is for. Downvote removed.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, I've never read or written a byte of C# before. I'm just correcting the other regex patterns that have been suggested here. If C# has a better solution (i.e. `string.Trim()`), you should add it as answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's really more robust to only remove leading/trailing space in this case. Suppose the input string was "\t4\n/13\n/2011\t\t", or "4/  13   /2011"? Wouldn't you want to fix that?

Comment: @Joshua Carmody, If the user provides garbage, and he gets garbage back, that's not lack of robustness. Undoing pretty printing without corrupting the value no matter what it might be, that's robustness. It'll work for all date-time formats.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private String stringclear(String str)
    {
        String tuslar = "qwertyuopasdfghjklizxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM._0123456789 :;-+/*@%()[]!\nüÜğĞİışŞçÇöÖ"; // also you can add utf-8 chars
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (tuslar.Contains(str[i].ToString()))  //from tuslar string. non special chars
                sb.Append(str[i]);
            if (str[i] == (char)13) // special char (enter key)
                sb.Append(str[i]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```